# canvas fillRect is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea what is wrong. This is being made on a completely new site, so there are no cache problems, and the javascript console isn't returning errors. The canvas spans over the whole page, and is tagged properly. Here is the script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var game = document.getElementById("game");
var context = game.getContext("2d");
var gamePieces = []
function gamePiece(width, height, color, x, y){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    update = function(){
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.height, this.width);
    }
    gamePieces[gamePieces.length] = this
}
var p1 = gamePiece(50, 50, "blue", 0, 0);
function update(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
    for(var i = 0; i < gamePieces.length; i++){
        gamePieces[i].update();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't assigned the `update` method to `this` so it cannot be accessed externally. Just use `this.update = function()...` instead.

Comment: Also, if you use cobstructor functions, then you need to use new <function name>

Comment: I doubt this doesn't throw errors

Comment: Yeah... There's more wrong with this than just what we've pointed out. No errors get thrown because he never calls `update`.

Comment: Don't worry guys, I fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out.
Everything is running smoothly, I just needed to add another context.fillstyle and context.fillRect() statement. derpyderp.

Comment: Oh great, now p1 is being called "undefined". gotta love computers.

Comment: False alarm again, just had more bad code to correct.